# Unable to start geomesa-accumulo

Tags: accumulo, geomesa

hduser@Neha-PC:/usr/local/geomesa-tutorials$ java -cp geomesa-tutorials-accumulo/geomesa-tutorials-accumulo-quickstart/target/geomesa-tutorials-accumulo-quickstart-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  org.geomesa.example.accumulo.AccumuloQuickStart  --accumulo.instance.id accumulo  --accumulo.zookeepers localhost:2184   --accumulo.user root  --accumulo.password PASS1234 --accumulo.catalog table1
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dgeomesa.hbase.coprocessor.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase/lib/geomesa-hbase-distributed-runtime_2.11-2.2.0.jar
Loading datastore
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Method org.locationtech.geomesa.security.AuthorizationsProvider.apply(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/locationtech/geomesa/security/AuthorizationsProvider; must be InterfaceMethodref constant
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStoreFactory$.buildAuthsProvider(AccumuloDataStoreFactory.scala:234)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStoreFactory$.buildConfig(AccumuloDataStoreFactory.scala:162)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(AccumuloDataStoreFactory.scala:48)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(AccumuloDataStoreFactory.scala:36)
    at org.geotools.data.DataAccessFinder.getDataStore(DataAccessFinder.java:121)
    at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(DataStoreFinder.java:71)
    at org.geomesa.example.quickstart.GeoMesaQuickStart.createDataStore(GeoMesaQuickStart.java:103)
    at org.geomesa.example.quickstart.GeoMesaQuickStart.run(GeoMesaQuickStart.java:77)
    at org.geomesa.example.accumulo.AccumuloQuickStart.main(AccumuloQuickStart.java:25)

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that all versions of GeoMesa on the classpath are the same. Just from your command, it seems you are at least mixing 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT with 2.2.0. Try checking out the git tag for tutorial project that corresponds to the GeoMesa version you want, as described [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/index.html#about-tutorial-versions). If you want to use a SNAPSHOT version, you need to make sure that you have pulled the latest changes for each project.